# How can I draw -> in forest?

Tags: forest

I want to draw like `-> 123` in this forest by `$\overset{\downarrow }{\mathop{123}}\,$`none as defaut
This is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[1[2[3[123]][4[124]][5[125]]]
[3[2[132]][4[134]][5[135]]]
[4[2[142]][3[143]][5[145]]]
[5[2[152]][3[153]][4[154]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I get like this, for example?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it all at once or do it node wise:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
if n children=0{edge={->}}{},
},
[1[2[3[123]][4[124]][5[125]]]
[3[2[132]][4[134]][5[135]]]
[4[2[142]][3[143]][5[145]]]
[5[2[152]][3[153]][4[154]]]]
\end{forest}

\begin{forest}
[1[2[3[123,edge={->}]][4[124,edge={->}]][5[125,edge={->}]]]
[3[2[132,edge={->}]][4[134,edge={->}]][5[135,edge={->}]]]
[4[2[142,edge={->}]][3[143,edge={->}]][5[145,edge={->}]]]
[5[2[152,edge={->}]][3[153,edge={->}]][4[154,edge={->}]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you want all lines to be like that, use `for tree={edge={->}}`

Comment: If I want edge is a curve, how can I do it?

Comment: @minthao_2011 You have to draw them yourself, I think.

Comment: @minthao_2011 Ask a new question if you want curves. Only you need to be more specific. What kind of curve? Which edges?

Comment: @cfr Thank you very much. I shall post another question as you said.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd prefer `forest` to ensure accuracy for the terminal nodes, for example:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
  if n children=0{
    edge={->}}{},
  },
  delay={
    for tree={
      where n children=0{
        content/.wrap 3 pgfmath args={#1#2#3}{content("!uuu")}{content("!uu")}{(content("!u"))}
      }{},
      where level=1{
        content/.pgfmath={int(n()+1)}
      }{},
    },
  },
  [1[[3[]][4[]][5[]]]
    [[2[]][4[]][5[]]]
    [[2[]][3[]][5[]]]
    [[2[]][3[]][4[]]]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

[image: calculate terminal nodes]